# split a string at specific position to array

Tags: arrays, string, split

I have got a string in PHP.

```
(check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l g -w 90 -c 95)
```

I want to split the string at the first `!` (between `check_nt` and `USEDDISKSPACE`) into two arrays.

I thought to use `strpos` to get the position of the first sign.
I don´t know how to split the string at the numeric position I get from `strpos` as return value.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Have you considered using a regular expression for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string to specific array position c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164946/split-string-to-specific-array-position-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you use PHP, so consider [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) in addition to [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```php
$str = "(check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l g -w 90 -c 95)";

$pos = strpos($str, "!");

$a = substr($str, 0, $pos);    // $a = "(check_nt"
$b = substr($str, $pos + 1);   // $b = "USEDDISKSPACE!-l g -w 90 -c 95)"
```

Other approach using [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```php
$str = "(check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l g -w 90 -c 95)";

$arr = explode("!", $str, 2);  // $arr[0] = "(check_nt"
                               // $arr[1] = "USEDDISKSPACE!-l g -w 90 -c 95)"
```

Note that both approaches remove the `!` to split at.

Comment: Your solution is good. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regular expression:

`^(\([^!]+)([ -~]+)$`

This will give you:

```
Grp 1.      `(check_nt`
Grp 2.      `!USEDDISKSPACE!-l g -w 90 -c 95)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
/^.*!/
```

will match to the first part of the string, while

```
/!.*$/
```

to the second part. But the implementation depends on the language you use.